# cURL to jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, curl

Really inexperienced and need a pure javascript api request. Any idea how to convert this cURL request to jquery ajax?

```
curl --get --include 'https://igdbcom-internet-game-database-v1.p.mashape.com/characters/?fields=*&limit=10' \
  -H 'X-Mashape-Key: DFGqKmjjWB********************4WVDjsnvStEw2yMsBIo' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$.ajax("https://igdbcom-internet-game-database-v1.p.mashape.com/characters/?fields=*&limit=10", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "X-Mashape-Key": "DFGqKmjjWB********************4WVDjsnvStEw2yMsBIo",
      "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: (data) => {
      console.log(data) // your data
    },
    error: (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

The `--include` flag in curl displays response headers. Updated to get them using jQuery.

---

Use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://igdbcom-internet-game-database-v1.p.mashape.com/characters/?fields=*&limit=10",
    headers: { 
      'X-Mashape-Key': 'DFGqKmjjWB********************4WVDjsnvStEw2yMsBIo',
      'Accept': 'application/json' 
    },
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data, textStatus, request){
      alert(request.getResponseHeader('some_header')); // Get a specific response header
    },
    error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(request.getResponseHeader('some_header')); // Get a specific response header
    }
  });
```

To get all the response headers, use `getAllResponseHeaders()`